# Setting condition in selectOutput block

Tags: anylogic

I have an `selectOutput` block in which I would like agents of type Patient to continue through OutT if they have passed through a particular `timeMeasureStart` block. After passing `agent.timeMeasureStart` in the condition, I receive 'timeMeasureStart' cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable for your agent type Patient. Let's say you name it tmsTrue. Make the variable of type `boolean`. In the `On Enter` field of the `timeMeasureStart` block write:

```
agent.tmsTrue = true;
```

[image]

Then set your select output condition as:

```
agent.tmsTrue == true
```

[image]

Of course make sure that the variable's initial value is set to false.

[image]

Comment: I am returned 'tmsTrue cannot be resolved or is not a field'

Comment: Did you create it for the agent? You said you are using an agent of type Patient. Go to the agent type Patient window and create the variable there.

Comment: Ah excuse me Emile, I had not set the ```Agent type``` to ```Patient``` in the various blocks. Your solution worked, thank you.